# Customer name missing in transaction mail in 2.4.6?

Tags: magento2, customer, transactional-mail

After updating to Magento 2.4.6, the customer name is missing in the order confirmation mail. This is the code I have in the mail template:

```
{{trans "%customer_name," customer_name=$order.getCustomerName()}}{{var order.getCustomerName()}}
```

It worked before I updated ... something changed I guess. How do I have to write that in Magento 2.4.6?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> {{trans "%customer_name," customer_name=$order.getCustomerName()}}

Change this line to:

> {{trans "%customer_name," customer_name=$order_data.customer_name}}

Additionally, remove the following line:

**{{var order.getCustomerName()}}**

The **getCustomerName()** method has been **deprecated** in recent Magento versions, **so you should directly access the customer_name property instead**. By making this change, you should be able to display the customer's name correctly in the order confirmation email.

**Reference File :**

```
vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Sales/email/order_new.html
```

Comment: Correct......+1